# How to export multiple queries into one Excel worksheet

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have some queries in my Access database. I know to Export These into one Excel workbook but in different Sheets. I want to list the results of the queries into one sheet and add one empty row and a caption between the results.

I don't know how can i handle it, could someone help me?

Comment: I'd export each query into a temporal sheet, paste it into the main and loop again. That's what I'd do.

Comment: what u mean with temporal sheet?

Comment: Instead of pasting the query into the sheet you want to. Paste it into a sheet.. for example "TempData", copy the TempData into your main sheet, delete everything into the TempData and loop again.

Comment: Use a union query to combine multiple queries into a single result and export that single query to Excel. Check https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-a-union-query-to-combine-multiple-queries-into-a-single-result-1f772ec0-cc73-474d-ab10-ad0a75541c6e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: Removed tags from title; trademark capitalization; grammar; noise reduction.

Answer (score 2):

Set a reference to Microsoft excel in the Access Vb Editor

```vb
Sub ExportQueries
Dim xl as New Excel.Application  'start up excel
dim wb as workbook
dim ws as worksheet
dim r as range
set wb = xl.workbooks.add      'add a workbook
set ws = wb.worksheets(1)      'point to first sheet
set r = ws.range("a1")         'point to a cell
r = "my first caption"
set r = r.offset(1,0)
'dim rs as new recordset        'ADO
Dim rs as recordset     'DAO
'   rs.open "myquery",currentproject.connection  'ADO
 Set rs = Currentdb.OPenrecordset("myquery")  'DAO


 '*************************Copy field headings into excel
 Dim f as field   
 dim x as integer
 For each f in rs.Fields
    r.offset(0,1)=f.name
    x = x+1
 next f
  set r = r.offset(1,0)
  '****************************End field headings


r.copyfromrecordset rs   'copy results into xl
rs.close
set r = r.end(xldown).offset(2,0) 'point to cell 2 below end of first set of results
r = "my next caption"
set r = r.offset(1,0)
rs.open "myotherquery",currentproject.connection
r.copyfromrecordset rs
rs.close
set r = r.end(xldown).offset(2,0)
'and so on

end sub
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your solution, i got error message with "dim rs as new recordset" i solved this with "Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("myquery")"...

Comment: But i dont get with this Code the column headings of my query results in Excel, do you know how can i Export this also?